# UICollectionView datasource update order

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

So I have an UICollectionView and the data source is just a simple array:

```
private(set) var selectedItems = [Item]() {
    didSet {
        updateTitle()
        adjustSelection()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return selectedItems.count
}
```

What is the correct order for removing an item, first from the collection view or from the data source?

```
func removeItemFromSelection(_ item: Item) {
    guard let index = selectedItems.firstIndex(of: item) else {
        return
    }

    collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
    selectedItems.remove(at: index)
}
```

So

```
collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
selectedItems.remove(at: index)
```

or

```
selectedItems.remove(at: index)
collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
```

Any documentation of this by any chance you know of?

The first variation crashes on iOS 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always first modify the model then update the view

```
selectedItems.remove(at: index)
collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
```

The **view** follows the **model**, it's just a rule.

When the data source is being populated the data is assigned to the array first and then `reloadData()` is called.

Comment: "Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Sections and Items:
To insert, delete, or move a single section or item, follow these steps:

Update the data in your data source object.
Call the appropriate method of the collection view to insert or delete the section or item."

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW1